# ArcMap: Copying multiple line features from one gdb to another gdb

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I've a file gdb where I regularly draw new lines. And are stored as individual line feature, e.g. with running number PCxxxx (xxxx is number). And have 2nd file gdb with extract of required line feature from the first gdb using arcmap

At times I'll need to update the line feature in the 1st gdb and didn't update the 2nd gdb.

Was wondering how can I update the 2nd gdb without physically pulling them one by one and copy to the 2nd gdb.

Comment: Each line is a feature class?

Comment: Yes, each line stored as a feature class.

Comment: There's a reason corn flakes are sold in a single large box, and not individually wrapped in plastic and cardboard. The same rule should apply to features in a feature class.

Comment: Noted that they (all lined) should be 1 feature class instead. Any suggestion on how to auto pulling the data to another gdb if all are held in one feature class?

Comment: You should be able to use Model Builder with [Iterate feature classes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-classes.htm) to copy each fc to the second gdb. You can also use arcpy, see [first code example here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm#C_GUID-8A401F3B-9693-4E56-9A9E-CDE60EC912D0)

Comment: If you merge all the individual line layers in the first gdb, and do the same for the second gdb, then run a join of the second gdb merged lines to the first to select all lines in the first with the same name, then export the selected features to a new layer you should be all set.  If you really want each line in its own layer, you can run a split by attributes using the name on the new merged layer.   You could also use the Feature Compare tool on the first and second merged layers.